# Web testing/Load testing for applications that uses JQuery

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, load-testing, web-testing

I try to develop a Web Test script in Visual Studio ultimate for an application that uses JQuery, but those components are not recognized for VS. Is there a way to do this type of test??

I use VS to created Web Test and then add those web tests to create a load test scenario.
But, We have a web application that use JQuery, when I record my test steps using the web test recorded, its not recording the browser operations. Visual studio fails to capture the browser operations performed on a JQuery web application.

Comment: Yes. But your question is too vague to give a useful answer. What exactly do you want to do, what have you tried. Have you looked at the Microsoft documentation on how to create web tests and, if yes, what did you not understand. An important point to understand is that Visual Studio's web tests work at the HTTP(S) level and so any "active" content in the web pages, such as JavaScript, will not be handled automatically.

Comment: I use VS to created Web Test and then add those web tests to create a load test scenario.
But, We have a web application that use JQuery, when I record my test steps using the web test recorded, its not recording the browser operations. Visual studio fails to capture the browser operations performed on a JQuery web application.

Comment: Please read my previous comment again. Pages such as http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2007/12/30/web-tests-work-at-the-http-layer.aspx explain how Web Tests work and they outline how to handle things like JQuery. There are many other useful web pages that a simple web search will find.